# Android upload image via HTTP PUT

Tags: android, image, http, fiddler, multipartentity

I'm trying to upload a jpeg image to my web server via an HTTP PUT method.

With Fiddler, I'm able to compose an HTTP PUT request, upload the image and execute the request successfully.

However, on Android, I can't get it to work. I've read many solutions about using MultipartEntity. When I try that, the image received on the server is corrupted. I compared the content of the original image with the one received by the server and I see that some HTTP headers are added at the beginning of the file and that the multipart boundary is added at the end, therefore corrupting it.

I've set up Fiddler on the web server as a reverse proxy to capture the incoming HTTP traffic:

[here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtCXX.png)

On the top, the HTTP PUT request sent with Fiddler that works.

At the bottom, the one sent by my Android application that sends a corrupted image.

How can I send an HTTP PUT request on Android that will produce a similar request than the one sent with Fiddler?

Comment: It's very unusual to see a `multipart` body for a `PUT` request; this is typically seen for a `POST` request instead.

It's unlikely that anyone will be able to debug this issue unless you update your question with the code you're using.

Comment: `my Android application that sends a corrupted image.`. No. It sends the image ok. But the receiver is saving the image and adds headers and boundary. I would blame the receiver. Who is receiving? Php? Show your android code please.

Comment: @greenapps: The page he's showing is my echo.aspx page which reflects back what the sender sent. But you're right that it would make more sense for him to be showing Fiddler's `Request Inspectors` instead.

Comment: @Francis BF I have the same issue, you have any solution for that? Thanks.